# How to enable a Convolutional NN to take variable size input?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

So, I've seen that many of the first CNN examples in Machine Learning use the MNIST dataset. Each image there is 28x28, and so we know the shape of the input before hand. How would this be done for variable size input, let's say you have some images that are 56x56 and some 28x28.

I'm looking for a language and framework agnostic answer if possible or in tensorflow terms preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, resizing the images appropriately (for example to keep the aspectratio) will be sufficient. But, this can introduce distortion, and in case this is harmful, another solution is to use Spatial Pyramidal Pooling (SPP). The problem with different image sizes is that it produces layers of different sizes, for example, taking the features of the `n-th` layer of some network, you can end up with a featuremap of size `128*fw*fh` where `fw`  and `fh` vary depending on the size of the input example. What SPP does in order to alleviate this problem, is to turn this variable size feature map into a fix-length vector of features. It operates on different scales, by dividing the image into equal patches and performing maxpooling on them. I think [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729.pdf) does a great job at explaining it. An example application can be seen [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.01381.pdf).

As a quick explanation, imagine you have a feature map of size `k*fw*fh`. You can consider it as `k` maps of the form

```
X Y
Z T
```

where each of the blocks are of size `fw/2*fh/2`. Now, performing maxpooling on each of those blocks separately gives you a vector of size `4`, and therefore, you can grossly describe the `k*fw*fh` map as a `k*4` fixed-size vector of features.

Now, call this fixed-size vector `w` and set it aside, and this time, consider the `k*fw*fh` featuremap as `k` featureplanes written as

```
 A B C D
 E F G H
 I J K L
 M N O P
```

and again, perform maxpooling separately on each block. So, using this, you obtain a more fine-grained representation, as a vector of length `v=k*16`.

Now, concatenating the two vectors `u=[v;w]` gives you a fixed-size representation. This is exaclty what a 2-scale SPP does  (well, of course you can change the number/sizes of divisions).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

When you use CNN for classification task, your network has two part:

1. *Feature generator*. Part generates feature map with size `WF x HF` and `CF` channels by image with size `WI x HI` and `CI` channels . The relation between image sizes and feature map size depends of structure your NN (for example, on amount of pooling layers and stride of them).
2. *Classifier*. Part solves the task of classification vectors with `WF*HF*CF` components into classes.

You can put image with different size into *feature generator*, and get feature map with different sizes. But classifier can only be training on some fixed lengths vectors. Therefore you obviously train your network for some fixed sizes of images. If you have images with different size you resize it to input size of network, or crop some part of image.

Another way described in the article

*K. He, X. Zhang, S. Ren, J. Sun, "Spatial pyramid pooling in deep convolutional networks for visual recognition," [arXiv:1406.4729](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729) 2014*

Authors offered **Spatial pyramid pooling**, which solve the problem with different image on the input of CNN. But I don't sure is spatial pyramid pooling layer exists in tensorflow.

Comment: So should the image be resized/cropped before generating the feature map, or is it the feature map that should be resized?

Comment: Most often way is to crop/resize image. But i gave a link to the article with another method. I advance to use simple way and crop/resize image before put it to network.